# Downloading hospitals and restaurants from OpenStreetMap in shapefile format

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, openstreetmap, guatemala

I need information on hospitals and restaurants in Guatemala.

How can I download this information from OpenStreetMap?

I want to use the data in ArcMap 10.1

Answer (score 4):

You can use the **QuickOSM** plugin to directly download only desired data, e.g. everything in Guatemala with amenity=hospital as shown in the following screenshot:

[image]

The data is downloaded and stored as (temporary) Shapefiles (in the Processing temp folder). I suggest using "Save as" to create permanent Shapefiles in a different folder with more descriptive names.

Answer (score 4):

With the QuickOSM plugin in QGIS, you can download OSM features as a shapefile. Open the "Quick query" dialog and set "amenity", "hospitals" in "Guatemala". You can save your shapefile in the "advanced" panel. You have to set a directory and a prefix. You may have to increase the timeout.

Answer (score 3):

In QGIS (can be done in ArcGIS)

You can download shapefiles from: 
http://download.geofabrik.de/central-america/guatemala.html

Once downloaded and unzipped (guatemala-latest.shp.zip) you can filter the restaurants and hospitals

[image]

Comment: Please take into account that restaurants might be modelled as single node but also as polygon (that might postprocessed to get the centeroid node)